# Android Studio : "Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project of type org.gradle.api.Project"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a newbie with Android Studio. I am trying to use this project library : https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup in my project.

So what I did is to import it as a module in my project ; with the name "androidtaggroup"

Now, I have got the following error at compilation:

```
"Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':androidtaggroup' of type org.gradle.api.Project."
```

Here is where the problem occurs in the Gradle file:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'me.gujun.android.taggroup.demo'
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME // ERROR HERE !!!!
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    }
```

Anybody can tell me how to fix this problem ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is to define your version name there or use a custom made variable. `project.VERSION_NAME` does not exists by default, therefore you can't use it. That is basically what the error message is telling you.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'me.gujun.android.taggroup.demo'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionName "1.2.3"
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
}
```

or alternative:

```
// somewhere above
def VERSION_NAME = "1.2.3"

// and the usage:
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'me.gujun.android.taggroup.demo'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionName VERSION_NAME
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
}
```

And after you have changed that you will probably run into the same issue for using `project.VERSION_CODE`:

```
versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
```

Fix is the same: provide a valid self defined variable or constant

Comment: Thanks !!! Just for my information, do you know why I get this error when I import this project as module and not when I use this project as standalone project ? Other question : now, I have got another error in the library/build.gradle file : "Could not read script maven-push.gradle as it does not exist." on this line of code : "apply from: '../maven-push.gradle'" . Do you know how to fix it ? Thanks !!!

Comment: The problem is that this project is a project and not a module. It already consists of 2 modules: demo and library. When you want to use the library, all you need to do is to add it as a dependency `compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'` (read their readme!). When you check the `gradle.properties` file in the project, you see the VERSION_CODE and VERSION_NAME properties you tried to use. That also explains where you had this from... TLDR: You can't add a project as a module.

Comment: Thanks Warren. But I don't understand their readme ! Step 1 : in which Gradle file should I add the line of code ? Once done, where will this me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar library be found ? Should I import their project before ? Maven : do I have to add this code and where ? Build paragraph : "run ./gradlew assembleDebug" ; how can I do that ? Where ? What is is for ?  I am lost in Android Studio... I really preferred Eclipse...

Comment: Warren : you can answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421771/import-of-a-library-in-android-studio-need-step-by-step-explanations  where I asked the question in details ! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    ext.room_version = '2.1.0-alpha01' // Add this line in your build gradle
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 'VERSION_NAME' was not defined in the ext{} from build.gradle(Project: 'PROJECT_NAME')