# Import of a library in Android Studio : need step by step explanations

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a newbie with Android Studio. I need to use this library in my project : https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup

I read their explanations but I don't understand how to proceed...

**Step 1**

```
Gradle

dependencies {
   compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
}
```

In which Gradle file should I paste this ? What does that mean ? Especially the "library:1.4@aar" ? Where will my project find this file and this folder structure me.gujun.android.taggroup ? Should I import the library project before ?

**Step 1 (part 2)**

```
Maven

<dependency>
    <groupId>me.gujun.android.taggroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

What does that mean ? Where do I paste this code ? Is it a second possibility instead of Gradle or should I do this in addition to Gradle ?

**Step 2 : ok ! :)**

**Step 3**

```
Build

run ./gradlew assembleDebug (Mac/Linux)
```

What does this do ? How can I do this ? Detailed steps ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is Step 1 (part 1). Add this `compile` statement into the `build.gradle` of your own app module.

After that AS should show you a "please sync" banner and you press "sync now". After that is done you can start using the library.

Step 1 (part 2) is not required when you use gradle. It is only needed when you use Maven instead of Gradle.

Step 3 is just to compile the project. It was mentioned in the readme in case you want to build the complete project from sources.
You can do that and some time in the future you probably need to run gradlew with a defined task. So just open a console, go to your project root and type `./gradlew assembleDebug` for a test run. If you are on Windows you need `gradlew.bat assembleDebug` (not sure if .bat is required but it should work).

You can, of course, test that same command with your own project. Should work there as well.

PS: I highly recommend to read the user guide (at least partially): https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html