# Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_CODE' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am quite new in Android Studio. 
Now I have after adding a new Module (ChatSDK) to my project following error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_CODE' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

All other help treads did not helped me, actually an error in the definition.

Here is my gradle  file:

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.blackunity.germanminelife.germanminelife"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionName '2.2'
    versionCode 3
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I read all other threads about this problem but nothing helped me. 
Can anybody help me by fixing this error? 
Thanks you all a lot!

Conga

Comment: Check this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420705/android-studio-could-not-get-unknown-property-version-name-for-project-of-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio : "Could not get unknown property 'VERSION\_NAME' for project of type org.gradle.api.Project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420705/android-studio-could-not-get-unknown-property-version-name-for-project-of-t)

Comment: I tried both before but it hasn’t worked. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `versionCode` explicitly and I think it will be better to remove duplicate of the `versionCode` property, result should look like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.blackunity.germanminelife.germanminelife"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionName '2.2'
    versionCode 3
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Or with predefined variable, like this:

```
def VERSION_CODE = 3

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.blackunity.germanminelife.germanminelife"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionName '2.2'
    versionCode VERSION_CODE
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```